# Manipulate the HTMLloaded in a webview control

Tags: android, android-widget, webview

I have a webview control to which i am loading a page form a website. I want to include a CSS file to the webpage once it is loaded. Is there any way i can get accesses to the content that is loaded in the webview?

I have no control over the website, so changeing the code there is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute javascript from java by using loadUrl method.

```
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:alert('hello world')");
```

Afterwards you can set css by using javascript method

```
var obj= document.getElementById(obj);
obj.style.visibility = "visible";
```

You can find a code sample to execute javascript from java code at WebViewDemo application here

http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/#svn/trunk/Samples/WebViewDemo